# A point $P$ on circle such that $QA,QP,QB$ are in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

$Q$ is a fixed point and $S$ is a fixed circle . A variable chord through $Q$ meets the circle at A and B. Find locus of P on this chord such that $QA,QP,QB$ are in Arithmetic Progression.

Could someone give me slight hint as how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

$QA\cdot QB$ is constant, $QP=(QA+QB)/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion with geometric progression. Besides, what is the locus of these points P?

Comment: I dont understand the presence of $QA.QB=constant;  This argument plays no role.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it looks simpler than I expected. For instance, consider a case when $Q$ lies outside the circle $S$ with the center $O$. Then $P$ is a midpoint of a chord $AB$, so the segment $OP$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Therefore $P$ belongs to a circle which is build on a diameter $OQ$.

Comment: According to the title, P is a point on the circle.

Comment: @Mick Oh, yes, I have just noticed it. But in the question is also stated that $P$ is on the chord $AB$. So, on *which* circle is $P$? If $P$ is on $S$, then $P$ coincides with $A$ or $B$. Then since $QA$, $QP$, and $QB$ are in arithmetic progression, all points $A$, $P$, and $B$ coincide.

Comment: Agree that the question is not clearly stated.

Answer (score 0):

If point $Q$ is outside circle $S$, then the answer is easy, because $P$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

A more interesting case arises if $Q$ is inside $S$. Without loss of generality, one may assume $Q$ to be the origin of a cartesian coordinates system, and the center $C=(x_0,0)$ of $S$ to lie on the $x$-axis. If $R$ is the radius of $S$, then the polar equation of the locus can be written as
$$
r(\theta)=\sqrt{R^2-x_0^2\sin^2\theta}.
$$
In rectangular coordinates this can be written as an implicit equation of fourth degree:
$$
(x^2+y^2)^2+x_0^2y^2=R^2(x^2+y^2).
$$